# How to declare array of parameterized object in Java?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have declare `PDPage` with `PDRectangle` parameter

```
Float width = 8.5f;
Float height = 5f;
Float dpi = 72f;
PDRectangle size = new PDRectangle(width*dpi, height*dpi);
PDPage page = new PDPage(size);
```

but I want to declare multiple `PDPage` with custom `PDRectangle` size in an array.

Something like not exactly:

```
ArrayList<PDPage> page = new ArrayList<PDPage(size)>();
```

Comment: Will all the `PDPage` objects have the same size?

Comment: In Java, we can use generics only on types, not values. Thus, we would write `.. = new ArrayList<PDPage>();`. If we need a `List` of `PDPage`s with a fixed `size`, we would need to subclass from `PDPage` and fixate the `size` in the subclass. --- Why is a `List<PDPage>` not sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between creating a list and initializing it's elements. The initialization of the list only cares about the generic class specification:

```
List<PDPage> page = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can then add multiple instances of `PDPage` with the custom `size` to it:

```
page.add(new PDPAge(size)); // This can be done multiple times, e.g. in a loop
```

Answer (score 1):

As Mureinik states in his answer, you first have to instantiate the list,

```java
ArrayList<PDPage> pages = new ArrayList<>();
```

before adding instances to it (e.g. ten times):

```java
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pages.add(new PDPage(size))
}
```

---

If strictly necessary that all objects in the list have the same dimensions you could in theory create a subclass:

```java
public class SpecialPDPage {
    private static final Float width = 8.5f;
    private static final Float height = 5f;
    private static final Float dpi = 72f;
    private static final PDRectangle size = new PDRectangle(width*dpi, height*dpi);

    public SpecialPDPage() {
        super(size);
    }
}
```

and then initialize the list and add objects as follows:

```java
ArrayList<SpecialPDPage> pages = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pages.add(new SpecialPDPage())
}
```